# <br><br><br> getting generated and showing only in Inspect Element

Tags: javascript, html, css, perl, template-toolkit

I am using perl with template toolkit to generate Web page and I changed some JS code on HTML file, After Editing there are `<br><br><br>` showed on UI and I have no Idea How and strange thing is that there is no `<br><br><br>` in source code, Only on Inspect element One can see  `<br><br><br>`.

**Inspect Element:**

```
<form name="data" action="a.pl" method="post" onsubmit="return checkage();">
<br><br><br>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
```

**Source Code:**

```
<form name="data" action="a.pl" method="post" onsubmit="return checkage();">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
```

Comment: maybe a line-break `\n` has been converted to `<br>` somewhere. You should check for existing line-breaks in your source. And be shure that the posted source code is really the source for the inspected element.

Comment: I have checked again for `\n` and posted source code is really the source for the inspected element,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that your editor has inserted the newlines. These are being translated to HTML line breaks. The newlines are not reflected in what you see because the actual codes representing a newline vary across operating systems

On Unix platforms, the native newline sequence is ASCII LF, and '\n' was simply defined to be that value.

On Microsoft Windows, applications usually represent a newline with two control characters: CR+LF

Answer (score -2):

delete the `<br>....s` from inspect elements window, but don't close inspect element window then check if something has happened to your code if yes then again go to inspect element window and cross check now if both are same then you can rest and if not copy content of your file and save in different location and see what happens.

these type of problem happens when you edit a part of code in inspect element window.

hope this helps.

Comment: On removing `<br><br><br>` simply spaces is removed as expected, I know that already.

Comment: you should start it again from the beginning, it helps me.. might it can help you.. :p @AbhishekBhasker